# How to fork an Altcoin Which has 0 Reward Block to continue mining after the LAST POW BLOCK

Tags: blockchain, block, altcoin, mining-reward, altcoin-development

Im trying to learn how is it possible to Hard Fork an Altcoin Blockchain to Continue the Mining Phase after the LAST POW BLOCK. The Block Reward is already 0 and the LAST POW stops at Block 8000. And want to know if there is a way to continue the mining after the 8000 without any SYNC Problem and Stuck Problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How much C++ experience do you have? Can you build the altcoin you're modifying?

Comment: The Coin is already built working without any issue. The only thing is I want to extend the POW after the LAST BLOCK 8000. And then I will be updating the nodes. My experience in C++ is Medium but I totally understand how the Blockchain works and how to compile the Wallets (Win, Mac and Linux). Thanks!

Comment: Did you create this altcoin? Is PoW stopping at block 8000 because of a bug, or because of an intentional limitation?

Comment: Yes! I created it myself. It is a POW/POS Coin with all the coin mined on the first block and then 0 reward until LAST BLOCK 8000 and it stays full POS ... BUT I dont want that for NOW ...I want to extend the POW 0 reward block

Comment: I don't understand. If all the coins are premined why is there ever a need for POW reward?

Comment: To keep the Blockchain running! If no POW, Blockchain will get stuck because of the Limited amount of coins.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know ,if you created the coin ,it will be very easy for u to extend the pos margin block area(those pow blocks:>)You not only need to differ the blocks when CreateNewBlock by nBestBlockHeight but also need to do some modifies in "getblock" message blocktype checking.
That's all i got ; If this helps please tip me some reputations guys,this new "50 reputation" for comments nearly silent me  .

Answer (score 0):

This is simply done by around 6 changes.  Check/follow [this commit](https://github.com/Tillkoeln/Kolschcoin/commit/db0310604e3c2539fa0c7e00e06fb5c2b0321f8b).

This enable again pow blocks even if the last pow block is hit.